# Using Xcode image catalogs in RubyMotion

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, xcode7, rubymotion

I have moved all my images from the resources directory of my RubyMotion project into the Media.xcassets ( asset catalog ). I am able to load all images from the imageset in my Storyboard, however not in my application though. The compiling works fine, however on start i get this error which says - '`Could not load the "i-newsfeed" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier`'.

[image]

Please above my project structure. Basically, I would like to know if its even possible to use Xcode image catalog in RubyMotion. Kind of confused as I couldn't find any proper resource in the internet as well. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rubymotion can work with xcode assets catalogs. You can verify that the catalog is getting picked up and compiled (which should happen automatically) by trying to load image manually from your code using something like:

```
UIImage.imageNamed("i-newsfeed")
```

If that works, then you have to look at how you load for NIB files and how images are referenced in the storyboard.